# Couldn't find Post without ID sidekiq error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I can't figure out what's going on with sidekiq.  I could've swore this worked yesterday, but I must have been dreaming.

Here's my worker class:

```
class TagPostWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: "tag"
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(options = {})
      current_user = User.find(options[:user_id])
  end

end
```

I've tried running this command on my show method in the Post:

```
TagPostWorker.perform_async({:user_id => current_user.id})
```

But I get this error:

```
2013-08-17T22:45:45Z 4029 TID-ors6jfr54 TagPostWorker JID-ae203958bb3bcee01c8f83ef INFO: start
2013-08-17T22:45:45Z 4029 TID-ors6jfr54 TagPostWorker JID-ae203958bb3bcee01c8f83ef INFO: fail: 0.003 sec
2013-08-17T22:45:45Z 4029 TID-ors6jfr54 WARN: {"retry"=>false, "queue"=>"tag", "class"=>"TagPostWorker", "args"=>[{"user_id"=>7}], "jid"=>"ae203958bb3bcee01c8f83ef", "enqueued_at"=>1376779545.9099338}
2013-08-17T22:45:45Z 4029 TID-ors6jfr54 WARN: Couldn't find Post without an ID
```

I don't understand how sidekiq could even be attempting to a Post since I'm not even calling it in the perform method.  Any ideas what could be going on?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also strange, I could've sworn I restarted Rails/sidekiq.

But I renamed the worker to TagWorker, restarted Rails/sidekiq and it started working again!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [this](http://thechangelog.com/earn-a-sidekiq-blackbelt/) blog post.

> It sounds ridiculous, but Sidekiq is so fast that it can run your
>   worker before your model even finishes saving.